# Generate list with every nth value from input

Tags: python, list

I had the following code:

```
return [p.to_dict() for p in points]
```

I changed it to only print every nth row:

```
n = 100
count = 0

output = []

for p in points:
    if (count % n == 0):
        output.append(p.to_dict())
    count += 1
return output
```

Is there a more pythonic way to write this, to acheive the same result?

Comment: What is `points`? Can you provide some data / reproducible code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `enumerate` and modulo on the index in a modified list comprehension  to filter the ones dividable by `n`:

```
return [p.to_dict() for i,p in enumerate(points) if i % n == 0]
```

List comprehension filtering is good, but in that case, eduffy answer which suggests to use slicing with a step is better since the indices are directly computed. Use the filter part only when you cannot predict the indices.

Improving this answer even more: It's even better to use `itertools.islice` so not temporary list is generated:

```
import itertools
return [p.to_dict() for p in itertools.islice(points,None,None,n)]
```

`itertools.islice(points,None,None,n)` is equivalent to `points[::n]` but performing lazy evaluation.

Comment: you forgot enumerate :)

Answer (score 5):

The list slicing syntax takes an optional third argument to define the "step".  This take every 3rd in a list:

```
 >>> range(10)
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 >>> range(10)[::3]
 [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enumerate` with list comprehension.

```
[p.to_dict()  for i, p in enumerate(points) if i %100 == 0]
```